# getJSON not fetching data

Tags: javascript, html, json

My code below is not fetching data from data.js
The page works fine when the JSON data is hard coded into the page.

```
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <script>
    function jsontest() {
        var text;
        $.getJSON("data.js", function(result) {
            text = result;
        });
        var obj = JSON.parse(text);
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML =
        obj.name + "<br>" +
        obj.street + "<br>" +
        obj.phone;
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="jsontest();">
    <h1>Testing Page</h1>
    <p id="content"></p>
</body>
```

My data looks like this

```
{"name":"John Johnson","street":"Oslo West 16","phone":"555 1234567"}
```

Am I making a simple nooby mistake?

Comment: You ordered a pizza online and you are eating the pizza as soon as you hang up the phone. It does not work that way unless you happen to be standing inside the pizza place with people that can read your mind. You need to wait for the pizza to be deliveered to you. AKA, you have to wait until the Ajax call is done before you can use the data. That is what the success callback is for. Welcome to the world of Asynchronous programming

Comment: `getJson` is an ajax call, which means the code around the call continues to run even if the data isn't back yet. You need to shove all the stuff after your `.getJson` call inside the handler function. Also you shouldn't need to parse json as it's expecting back type json, as long as your data is formatted correctly and you pass the correct headers from the server you are covered. See the docs for ref: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: If you call the file `data.json` and your server responds with the correct mime-type `application/json`, you shouldn't use `JSON.parse();`, because the data you get already is a json object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I notice is that you're using `getJSON` in sync mode. This won't work since it's executed asynchronous. You need to place your logic inside finish handler

```
function jsontest() {
    var text;
    $.getJSON("data.js", function(result) {
        text = result;
        var obj = JSON.parse(text);
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML =
        obj.name + "<br>" +
        obj.street + "<br>" +
        obj.phone;          
    });
}
```

In your code, by the time you do

```
var obj = JSON.parse(text);
```

method `getJSon` didn't return yet so `text` contains the default value. It sends the request to the server and continue method flow without waiting for the result.

That's what the handler is for: to put logic that needs to be executed when request is complete.

Answer (score 1):

`$.getJSON` is an async call - so when you try and run `JSON.parse` outside the callback, it won't work since the call is still in progress. Move your code to the callback and you'll be good:

```
function jsontest() {
    $.getJSON("data.js", function(result) {
        var text = result;

        var obj = JSON.parse(text);
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML =
          obj.name + "<br>" +
          obj.street + "<br>" +
          obj.phone;
    }); 
    //Anything after the `getJSON` call is executed immediately. 
    //$.getJSON is still in progress when these lines are executing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is single-threaded and non-blocking, as a result, while the ajax call is being executed the program counter will continue. Thus will be parsing something which is undefined.

If you put the code beneath the ajax callback inside it, it will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your code inside the callback, or you wont have the text var populated:

```
function jsontest() {
    var text;
    $.getJSON("data.js", function(result) {
        text = result;
        var obj = JSON.parse(text);
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML =
        obj.name + "<br>" +
        obj.street + "<br>" +
        obj.phone;
    });

}
```